# How to create a keyframe with Python API for 3D Studio Max

Tags: python, python-2.7, 3dsmax

Currrently I'm creating keyframes with autokey, like this:

```
MaxPlus.Animation.SetAnimateButtonState(True)  # autokey on
MaxPlus.Animation.SetTime(time)                # Set time slider to chosen time of keframe
obj.Position = MaxPlus.Point3(x, y, z)         # Set position
MaxPlus.Animation.SetAnimateButtonState(False) # autokey off
```

But this is not really convinient. Is there any other way? Is there a function like:
createKeyframe(time, value)? How to access visibility controller?

I should probbably use:

```
c = MaxPlus.Factory.CreateDefaultFloatController()
obj.ParameterBlock.Parameter.SetController(c)
```

But still I do not know how to insert keyframes and I only know how to set them with AutoKey, so this changes nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With max 2016, there's hardly a better way than what you're doing. Sure, you can assign a new visibility controller:

```
node.SetVisibilityController(MaxPlus.Factory.CreateDefaultFloatController())
```

Or you can modify any existing one:

```
node.GetSubAnim(0).AddNewKey(time, param)
```

where param is a sum of any of

```
MaxPlus.Constants.AddkeyFlagged
MaxPlus.Constants.AddkeyInterp
MaxPlus.Constants.AddkeySelect
```

but to work with the values of the keys, you have to get the `IKeyControl/ISetKeyControl` interface. This won't work:

```
ctrl.GetInterface(MaxPlus.AnimatableInterfaceIds.IKeycontrol)
```

as it expects `MaxPlus.Interface_ID` type and `IKeycontrol` (which stands for the original `I_KEYCONTROL` here) is instead a const of value `0x00001100`. However, the original implementation goes something like:

```
void* Control::GetInterface(ULONG id)
{
    if (id==I_CONTROL) {
        return this;
    }
    else if (id==I_KEYCONTROL) {
        ...;
    }
    // and so on, only as a last resort checking the Interface_ID
    else {
        return Animatable::GetInterface(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any update for this as of Max 2018? I'm also trying to get keyframes in MaxPlus and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Any reason to avoid using pymxs for that part?

Comment: Good point, I guess not. I'm just starting with python in Max (finally upgraded from 2016) and was sticking to MaxPlus because I thought it had everything pymxs has, but now I'm reading the docs looks like that would be pretty simple actually.

Comment: @Swordslayer if you could post an example it would be very useful